# In React-Native, can I add hitSlop values to StyleSheet.create?

Tags: react-native

In React-Native, I defined the `hitSlop` prop in my `TouchableHightlight` component. I was wondering if I could add the properties to the function `StyleSheet.create()` and if it would make sense as well?

Here is a sample of the code I have:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
});

const MyComp = () => (
  <TouchableHighlight hitSlop={{ top: 8, left: 8, right: 8, bottom: 8 }}>
  </TouchableHighlight>
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object that you pass to `hitSlop` has strictly defined keys, limited to top, left, bottom and right. The result of `StyleSheet.create()` is an incompatible type and so it will throw an error like this:

> JSON value '84' of type NSNumber cannot be converted to UIEdgeInsets

Here is an example of the error:

[image: Simulator error example]

Answer (score 6):

Definitively `hitSlop` can not be part of a StyleSheet, but what you can do is to create a variable for that value, so that is not recreated on each render.

```
const MY_COMP_HIT_SLOP = { top: 8, left: 8, right: 8, bottom: 8 }

const MyComp = () => (
  <TouchableHighlight hitSlop={MY_COMP_HIT_SLOP}>
  </TouchableHighlight>
)
```

This is actually recommended by React Native folks on a prop that works in a similar way: `pressRetentionOffset` ([reference](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback#pressretentionoffset))

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so

A StyleSheet is an abstraction similar to CSS StyleSheets. Stylesheets are meant only for style properties (such as height, width, color etc).

Since hitSlop is more of a feature rather than a style, I think it should not be a part of StyleSheet property.